# Trying to redirect <enter> and second response to linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell, stdin

I'm trying to automate a process that creates a binary response file using a java program wrapped by a sh script (so many things wrong with this, but not my code).  The result I want requires hitting [enter] for the first prompt and 'Y'[enter] for the second prompt when running the sh script.

I got it to work on one Linux box using the following code:

`` echo Y > ans; ./script < ans `echo -e \\\r` ``

On another Linux box, it's not working (script goes into an infinite loop, again, not my code).  Both boxes run the same kernel and version.

There are more elegant, straightforward ways of doing this, I'm sure.  However, I need it to work consistently.  I'm not convinced it isn't the way one of the boxes is setup.

Comment: It would probably be more reliable to run `expect` for this kind of thing.

Comment: `(echo; echo Y) | ./script` ?

Comment: Hi! Do you know which part of your code is looping? Do you know for sure it's looping (as opposed to just hanging waiting for more input)? Also, I'm not sure exactly what input you want the code to get; if it's the characters "Y\r\n", then `printf "Y\r\n" | ./script` should do it.

Comment: The command ``./script < ans `echo -e \\\r`⁠`` doesn't make any sense. It invokes `./script` *with an argument* that is a carriage return, and with input from the file `ans` — i.e., it's like `./script $'\r' < ans`. I'm going to make a wild guess that the argument is ignored. Then I'm going to make an educated guess that the program issues the first prompt, reads the `Y` line from the `ans` file, issues the second prompt, and tries to read a second line of input. But, since it's at the end of the `ans` file, it gets an EOF. Some (stupid) programs react to EOF by trying the read again, forever.

Answer (score 1):

Try a simple `expect` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20
spawn /path/to/your/java/shell/script/thing.sh

expect "FirstPrompt:" { send "\r" }
expect "SecondPrompt:" { send "Y" }
interact
```

...where `FirstPrompt` is the text of the first prompt (so if your shell script thing promps "Please press ENTER" then you need that, verbatim, where I have written "FirstPrompt:" in the sample `expect` script) and SecondPrompt is the second promt, verbatim.

...I also assume `expect` is installed, and is located at `/usr/bin/expect` on your system. If that is not the case, then install it, and use the correct path.

Comment: Installed inspect and wrote a script.  For some reason the second prompt refuses to acknowledge the send.  Just stops; waiting for a human response.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn "/u01/app/11.2.0.4/grid/OPatch/ocm/bin/emocmrsp"

expect "Email address/User Name: " { send "\r" }
expect "Do you wish to remain uninformed of security issues (\[Y\]es\, \[N\]o) \[N\]:  " { send "Y" }

interact
`

Comment: try 'Y\r' as the response.

Comment: same result; just hangs waiting for human intervention

Comment: try adding a new, unconditional ``send`` of just "\r", after the "Y". So you're sending "Y" when prompted, and then ENTER afterwards.

Comment: Nope. Comes back and gives the first prompt again...if I'm not fast enough to response to the second prompt.

Comment: I don't understand "If you are not fast enough to respond". This is scripted; is the response not happening automatically, and quickly?

Comment: It has to be something about this script which is supplied by Oracle.  I've been encountering a number of frustrating quirks making it nearly impossible to automate a number of processes regarding the installation and patching for Oracle software.  It's like do it manually or use Cloud Control, but heaven forbid let this work using Chef or any other useful OS tools.